# listview adapter repete os valores salvos em id

Tags: android

Eu estou tentando trazer os valores do banco de dados e carregar em uma listview, eu já trago do banco um objeto com os dados (uma lista de "modulos"), e tentei passar o id da linha correspondente no banco via Intent para a outra activity carregar os valores correspondentes ao id que foi passado, o problema é que o adapter carrega os dados do banco colocando cada item certinho no listView, mas o id ele só passa para outra activity como intent com o valor 1, indepentente de qual seja o id verdadeiro.

segue o trecho de codigo:

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ViewHolder holder;
    if(convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)
context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_adapter,null);
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.tituloView = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.titulo2);
        holder.progressBar =
(ProgressBar)convertView.findViewById(R.id.progress);
        holder.button = (Button)convertView.findViewById(R.id.buttonModulo);

    }else{
        holder = (ViewHolder)convertView.getTag();
    }

    modulos = new Modulos();
    modulos = modulosList.get(position);

    Log.i("idModulo:"," "+modulos.getId());
    String titulo = modulos.getTitulo();
    holder.tituloView.setText(titulo);

    baixarImagem(convertView,modulos,context,holder);

    holder.progressBar.setMax(8);



    holder.progressBar.setProgress(4);

    holder.button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {


            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
            bundle.putString("id",modulos.getId());
            Intent intent = new Intent(context, ListaAulasActivity.class);
            intent.putExtras(bundle);
            intent.addFlags(intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            Log.i("idModuloEnviado: ",""+modulos.getId());
            context.startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

    convertView.setTag(holder);
    return convertView;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para chamar os atributos de cada item da lista, use OnItemClickListener no ListView.

```
seuListView.setOnItemClickListener(onCliqueItemLista());
```

Evento:

```
private AdapterView.OnItemClickListener onCliqueItemLista() {
    return new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            idModulo = modulosList.get(position).getId();
            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
            bundle.putString("id",modulos.getId());
            Intent intent = new Intent(context, ListaAulasActivity.class);
            intent.putExtras(bundle);
            intent.addFlags(intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            Log.i("idModuloEnviado: ",""+modulos.getId());
            context.startActivity(intent);
        }
    };
}
```

Comment: Funcionou!!! Voce é um genio cara! fiquei muito tempo travado nisso...
mas sabe me dizer como eu faco para que o evento de clique fique no botao, e nao no item inteiro?

Comment: Acho que o problema está no seu ViewHolder, pois ele é usado com RecyclerView. Parece que você criou um Adapter para seu ListView, o que é outra forma de fazer, mas nesse caso não é necessário ViewHolder, remova ele e pegue seus componentes do convertView. O evento de clique para o botão deve ser tratado dentro da classe do seu Adapter customizado.